# Data leakage through loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to download an html of a webpage via `AsyncTask` and then, show that html in the LOGs.

This is my code. However, when I run the code, loop never stops.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            URL myUrl;

            try{
                myUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data  = reader.read();
                while(data != -1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            String result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities").get();
            Log.i("asd",String.valueOf(result));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Logs get filled with:**

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 297K, 20% free 2582K/3200K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
```

Any Idea whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is `data` will not change after you initialized it with a single `read()` call, so it will never be `-1` (hence the infinite loop).

You need to call `read()` inside the loop.

Replace the following:

```
int data  = reader.read();
while(data != -1){
    // ...
```

With something like this:

```
int data;
while ((data = reader.read()) != -1) {
    // ...
```

To make things faster you could use a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String line = null;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}

String data = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Now the data which is being downloaded is missing.

Comment: yea,Perfect.Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of creating a new string on every character received. Do NOT do this:

```
result += current;
```

Instead, create a `StringBuilder` and append to it.

Or, better yet, do not read one character at a time, but create a `BufferedReader` and read into a buffer of a considerable size, e.g. 1024 bytes.

Comment: @Junaid, SO is not a coding service. You have everything you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the data with your code. I believe you already add internet permission when testing.

But your code blocks UI thread because of task.execute().get(). I changed it a bit:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Listener mListener;

DownloadTask(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String result = "";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL myUrl;

    try {
        myUrl = new URL(urls[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            result += current;
            data = reader.read();
        }

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    mListener.deliverResult(s);
}

public interface Listener {
    void deliverResult(String result);
}
```

}

And the code in Activity looks like:

```
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask(new DownloadTask.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void deliverResult(String result) {
            Log.i("asd",String.valueOf(result));
        }
    });
    task.execute("http://www.posh24.com/celebrities");
```